# I can't install any npm package

Tags: npm

I keep getting this error every time I try to install npm package :

````
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/json-server failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com proxy.company.com:8181
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! ```
````

Comment: This may be caused by a incorrect proxy setting in your npm config.

Comment: Can you tell more about the environment? What version of NPM are you using? And have you tried `npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>` and 
`npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>`?

Comment: @PeterBode no i do not know what to write in proxy-server-url ? 
could you please show me an example

Comment: @AbdelazizMohamed I had to look around, but there is a website that tells you this info: http://amibehindaproxy.com/

Comment: @PeterBode okay thanks alot I will check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you've misconfigured your proxy infos, here's how to configure it for npm from your cli :

```
npm config set proxy http://{user}:{password}@{proxy-url}:{proxy-port}
npm config set https-proxy http://{user}:{password}@{proxy-url}:{proxy-port}
```

and if you're not behind a proxy :

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

hope it can help.

Comment: Thank you I am not supposed to be behind a proxy and seems I config it by mistake, you answer solved my problem. Can't thank you enough